# How to set up progressive jpegs using fresco in android

Tags: android, facebook, fresco

I have just started using fresco and I have followed the steps in their documentation. I have been able to load URIs into the SimpleDraweeView within my listview adapter and now I am trying to implement progressive jpegs(images increase in quality as they load). The problem is that the code they have given in the site is not working as expected. The Uri is being loaded, but not progressively(The image is not gradually increasing in quality as it loads). Is there something I am missing or have forgotten to add?

Here is my build dependency:

```
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.13.+'
```

I have already added this in my application class:

```
//For fresco
 Fresco.initialize(this);
```

Here is my xml

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/tag_iv_tu"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/tu_tag_side"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/tu_tag_height"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha" />
```

And here is the code within the getView() method in my listview adapter

```
ImageRequest request = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(fileUri)
                            .setProgressiveRenderingEnabled(true)
                            .build();
                    DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                            .setImageRequest(request)
                            .setOldController(holder.tag_iv_tu.getController())
                            .build();
                    holder.tag_iv_tu.setController(controller);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set the ResizeOption for the ImageRequst,because the progressily depends on ResizeOptions.

Try this:

```
ResizeOptions options = new ResizeOptions(width, height);

ImageRequest request = ImageRequestBuilder
            .newBuilderWithSource(Uri.parse(uri))
            .setProgressiveRenderingEnabled(true).setResizeOptions(options)
            .build();
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but is there any way I can make it start as blurred then slowly improve quality like the way instagram does it?

Comment: @PatriceAndala, did you found any way to do the blur thing with progressive jpeg's?

Comment: Nope, still waiting for an answer

Comment: @PatriceAndala i think your jpeg needs to support this. in [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) there is an option where you can export jpegs with progressive loading feature.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
        String url ="http://...";
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);

        ImageRequest request = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(uri)
                .setProgressiveRenderingEnabled(true)
                .build();

        DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                .setImageRequest(request)
                .setOldController(image.getController())
                .build();

        mSimpleDraweeView.setController(controller);
```